# PHP - Can't set session variable as class staticdefault value

Tags: php, class, session-variables

How can i set `$dbname` to change as session value changes in this class?
i always get error whatever i try.

```
class db_config
{

    // default connection
    public static $dbname = $_SESSION['db_to_use']; // Your database name
    public static $dbuser = 'root'; // Your database username
    public static $dbpass = 'xxxxxxx'; // // Your database password
    public static $dbhost = 'localhost';
....

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get? Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Did you use `session_start()` ?

Comment: You __can't__ init class property with a dynamic value, create a setter instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something along these lines:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['db_to_use'] = 'mydatabase';

class db_config
{

    // default connection
    public static $dbname = '';
    public static $dbuser = 'root'; // Your database username
    public static $dbpass = 'xxxxxxx'; // // Your database password
    public static $dbhost = 'localhost';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setDbName();
    }

    public function setDbName()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['db_to_use']) && !empty($_SESSION['db_to_use'])) {
            self::$dbname = $_SESSION['db_to_use']; // Your database name
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$con = new db_config();
echo 'db_name : ' . $con::$dbname;
```

Comment: It worked for me , on top i prefer always to use :

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

also this line has no sense to me : $_SESSION['db_to_use'] = 'mydatabase';

thanks

Comment: `$_SESSION['db_to_use'] = 'mydatabase';` I just added to demonstrate the code functions. You're welcome.